# Test an API with Python

Tags: python, api, testing, pytest, web-api-testing

I am writing some tests for an API using Python and PyTest.

The tests are something like this:

```
def test_stackoverflow():
    response = stackoverflow(parameter1, parameter2)
    assert response.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK
    data = response.json()
    assert type(data['name']) is str
    assert data['lastname'] == "Wilson"
```

which call a function in another file containing the real API call:

```
def stackoverflow(parameter1, parameter2):
    return my_session.post("/api/endpoint",
                        params={
                            "parameter1": parameter1,
                            "parameter2": parameter2
                        })
```

This structure has two main problems:

1. When I write a test I have to remember/recheck the name of the parameters (like `name` and `lastname` in the example).
2. If the name of a parameter changes, I have to manually change it everywhere.

How could I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not a 100% sure, I understand your problem, but let me state two things:

**(1) My function stackoverflow has parameters hardcoded. Can we not change that?**

Yes, we can! Read up on the proper [usage of kwargs](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs#:%7E:text=Introduction%20to%20%2Aargs%20and%20%2A%2Akwargs%20in%20Python.%20In,number%20of%20arguments%20to%20pass%20in%20the%20functions.), which introduces key-word-arguments, so that you can formulate your API-calling function can be formulated as follows:

```
def stackoverflow(**kwargs):
    return my_session.post("/api/endpoint", params=kwargs)
```

Just, that in this case you would have to call the function as follows:

```
response = stackoverflow(key1=val1, key2=val2)
```

which would then pass two query/url-parameters to your API-call, namely key1 and key2 with values val1 and val2, respectively.

**(2) I have to fix parameters for every test. Can I not do that globally for all tests that I need?**

Yes sir/mam! Using [the very useful fixture-decorator](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/fixtures.html#:%7E:text=pytest%20fixtures%20are%20designed%20to%20be%20explicit%2C%20modular,known%20parameters%29%20or%20content%20%28such%20as%20a%20dataset%29.) can heavily simplify life with defining parameters for wherever you need them.

**Little note on the side:** try to use isinstance for type-assertions, e.g. isinstance(data['name'], str).